# Using http headers for passing data for logging

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, log4net

I am developing a windows application which communicates with ASP.Net Web API. I need to implement a dynamic logging strategy (using log4net) for the Web API where important information is logged automatically.
I was thinking of using http headers for this.
For example, I could use a prefix such as "X-Log-" for my headers. And the logger on the Web API would automatically pick this up and log all headers with that prefix.

However, I would have a number of questions regarding the above.

1. Is this a standard practice or is it an anti-pattern?
2. Can it pose any security risks if sensitive data is placed in the headers (assuming ssl is used)?
3. Could a firewall be configured to block requests which have a specific header?

Comment: The answers to all four questions is "yes".

Comment: thanks for your reply. So it's both a standard practice and an anti-pattern? :)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: What about the security risk please? If you use SSL, woudln't the he headers get encrypted as well?

Comment: Well yeah but the user running the client application could read the data if they want to, through various means.

Comment: Headers wont be encrypted, AFAIK. You'll need to encrypt it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answers to your questions can be answered with "it depends".

Is it a standard practice?  I've never seen it done, but that doesn't mean it's bad if it's implemented in a concise and explicit way.  It does tie your front-end to the API which could be a potential red flag.  It might be better to have an API endpoint specifically for logging.

Any security risk would depend upon what you (and your users) consider to be sensitive information and if that information is available elsewhere.  If it is available on the screen already, then I wouldn't worry too much about it as long as you are going over HTTPS.  If it is not something on the screen, then you would need to think about it more.

And, yes, a firewall could block incoming requests with those headers.

Hope that helps.